# Baby rudin theorem 8.8

Tags: real-analysis

how he found the two inequalities (56 and the last)?
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For (56), apply the triangle inequality to
$$z^n = P(z) - a_0 - a_1 z - \cdots - a_{n-1} z^{n-1}$$
to obtain
$$R^n \le |P(z)| + |a_0| + |a_1| R + \cdots + |a_{n-1}| R^{n-1}.$$

I believe the same idea works for the last inequality in the screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

The last inequality is achieved as follows.

$ |Q(re^{i\theta})|$
$=|1+b_k r^k e^{ik\theta}+b_{k+1}r^{k+1}e^{i(k+1)\theta}+ \dots +b_{n}r^{n}e^{in\theta}|$
$\le|1+b_k r^k e^{ik\theta}|+|b_{k+1}r^{k+1}e^{i(k+1)\theta}|+ \dots +|b_{n}r^{n}e^{in\theta}|$
$=1-r^k |b_k|+|b_{k+1}|r^{k+1}+ \dots +|b_{n}|r^{n}$
$=1-r^k$ {$|b_k|-r|b_{k+1}|-\dots-r^{n-k}|b_{n}|$ }